# Form component in VS toolbox

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, components

When I create a Component in VS it automatically appears in toolbox and can be used in design area of other components. However, when I create a Form (which also derives from Component) then I cannot add it to the toolbox.

1. Can this be changed so that a Form can be used as a Component?
2. If no, is there a specific reason why?

Comment: Can't you just right-click 'All Windows Forms' (at the top of the toolbox), select 'Choose items' and then select the 'Form' item from the list there?

Comment: Forms are not being listed in this dialog for some reason.

Comment: Any specific reason for downvoting?

Comment: I didn't down vote this.  I think it's a perfectly good question.  What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Brian, this was a general question to whoever downvoted it, not you specifically. The original question was about VS2008, but (as I have checked just now) VS2012 behaves the same way.